# Can Rules be used to disable the logo variable on some pages?

Tags: rules, theming

I have a change in Drupal 6 that I would like to make quickly without doing another SVN roll (until I get a more permanent solution in place) and I would like to create a triggered rule that will null the $logo variable that is being sent to the theme before it gets there.

I know how to tell it to identify the page in question and control it based on role. However, I am having trouble figuring out what PHP code to use in the custom PHP code section. Partly because I just don't know what variables are available nor at what point in the code flow I am sitting in (which is important for this).

Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that I'm on the wrong way (correct me if) but I think you should do a `hook_preprocess_page(&$vars)` in your theme's `template.php` and unset the `$var['logo']` when you meet your condition.

I wouldn't do that with Rules, I don't even know if it's possible.